# Crop a raster image with the coordinates in a CSV file in Python

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, rasterio

I am trying to crop a satellite image with geographical coordinate from  a CVS file. I have never cropped an image using coordinates from CSV file. I tried searching a lot but I can only find cropping using a shapefile. Can someone guide me or give me a link of tutorial  or something where they have cropped using a CSV file. I really don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question also as geopandas and rasterIO: find below a solution with pandas and rasterIO. QGIS should be also possible, there you can try to make a QgsVectorLayer from your CSV and then it would be the same like shapefile, because the class is the same.
Here the rasterIO solution: it takes a CSV with the following structure:
*id,x,y

1,0,0

1,0,50

1,50,50

1,50,0

1,0,0*
you can put more Polygons into it with different ids. The code is like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
from matplotlib import pyplot
from rasterio.plot import show

polygons = []
df = pd.read_csv('polys.csv')
for id, p in df.groupby('id'): 
    poly = Polygon(zip(p.x,p.y)) #
    polygons.append(poly)

with rasterio.open("LC.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, polygons, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
         "height": out_image.shape[1],
         "width": out_image.shape[2],
         "transform": out_transform})

    with rasterio.open("LC_masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)

#showing the results
src=rasterio.open("LC.tif")
masked = rasterio.open("LC_masked.tif")
fig, (ax1, ax2) = pyplot.subplots(1,2, figsize=(21,7))   
show((src, 1), ax=ax1, title='Original')
show((masked, 1), ax=ax2, title='Masked')
pyplot.show()
```

[image]